# What is the best approach to store menu items in a web application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, menubar

I am going to develop a web application using *J2EE*. I need to implement a menubar for my application (like any other menubar) and I want to know what is the best approach to storing menu items in my application. For example:

1. Storing menu and submenu info in DB and retrieving them.
2. Using another structures like a XML file.
3. ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Storing menu items in the xml would be good option.Advantages are

1. It would be easy to parse a xml and structure it according to you need.
2. There will be no need of db hit or a round trip, XML can be parsed using java script which would be a light weigh and a front operation.

Answer (score 1):

In my recent project we've stored navigation objects in DB.

Pros:

- security (if user role has been changed you can receive real-time response with new navigation)
- no reasons to deal with security in Front (pros for front-end developers)

Cons:

- to many requests (especially if this very high loaded system)
- big amount of work for Back end developers